Derivation or origin of projection tensor
Can the projection tensor that is used in General relativity be derived using formal mathematics?
In GR, the projection tensor orthogonal to a non-null vector is defined as,
$$ P_{\mu \nu} =  g_{\mu \nu} - u_{\mu} u_{\nu},
$$
where $u_{\mu}$ has unit norm. How does one even come up with such a definition? Is it coming from formal differential geometry?

This is very simple linear algebra, not even differential geometry. You first need to understand things at the level of one vector space; for the differential geometry case, you just apply this reasoning one tangent space at a time.
Suppose in general $(V,g)$ is a pseudo-inner product space and that $T\subset V$ is a non-degenerate subspace (meaning that the $g$-orthogonal subspace $S:=T^{\perp}$ is actually complementary, i.e $V=S\oplus T$, meaning that for every $v\in V$, there exist unique $s\in S$ and $t\in T$ such that $v=s+t$). The orthogonal direct sum decomposition $V=S\oplus T$ now gives us two projection operators $P_S:V\to S\subset V$ and $P_T:V\to T\subset V$ (namely, such that for all $v\in V$, $P_S(v)\in S$, and $P_T(v)\in T$ are the unique vectors such that we have  $v=P_S(v)+P_T(v)$).
So, we have the orthogonal projection map $P_T:V\to T$. The question now is can we get some ‘simple’ formula for this? Yes, we can. Fix a $g$-orthonormal basis $\{t_1,\dots, t_k\}$ for $T$, meaning a basis for $T$ such that $g(t_i,t_j)=\pm\delta_{ij}$. For concreteness, let’s denote $\tau_i:= g(t_i,t_i)\in\{\pm 1\}$. For each $v\in V$, we have the obvious equality that
\begin{align}
v=\left(v-\sum_{i=1}^k\tau_ig(v,t_i)\cdot t_i\right) + \sum_{i=1}^k\tau_ig(v,t_i)\cdot t_i.\tag{$*$}
\end{align}
The second term clearly lies in the subspace $T$. I claim that the first term actually lies in $S=T^{\perp}$; to show this, let us check that the $g$-inner product with each of the basis vectors in $\{t_1,\dots, t_k\}$ vanishes. So, for any $j\in\{1,\dots, k\}$, we have
\begin{align}
g\left(v-\sum_{i=1}^k\tau_ig(v,t_i)\cdot t_i\,\,,\,\, t_j\right)&=
g(v,t_j)-\sum_{i=1}^k\tau_ig(v,t_i)g(t_i,t_j)\\
&=g(v,t_j)-\tau_jg(v,t_j)g(t_j,t_j)\\
&=g(v,t_j)-\tau_j^2 g(v,t_j)\\
&=g(v,t_j)-1\cdot g(v,t_j)\\
&=0.
\end{align}
By linearity in the second slot, it follows that for all vectors $t\in T$, the vector $v-\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\tau_ig(v,t_i)\cdot t_i$ is orthogonal to $t$, and thus this vector lies in the subspace $S$. Therefore, we have the decomposition
\begin{align}
v=\underbrace{\left(v-\sum_{i=1}^k\tau_ig(v,t_i)\cdot t_i\right)}_{=P_S(v)} + \underbrace{\sum_{i=1}^k\tau_ig(v,t_i)\cdot t_i}_{=P_T(v)}\quad\in S\oplus T.\tag{$**$}
\end{align}
In particular, we have found a simple formula for the projection operators $P_S,P_T$ once we’re given an ‘orthonormal’ basis for $T$ (btw, notice that logically speaking in this entire discussion, the roles of $S$ and $T$ have been completely symmetric; the only asymmetry which comes up is because I decided to use an orthonormal basis for $T$ to describe things… I could have instead taken an orthonormal basis for $S$ to describe things and I’d get corresponding formulae).
Observe that $P_T:V\to V$ is an endomorphism of $V$ with values in $T$, i.e it’s equivalent to a $(1,1)$-tensor on $V$. We can use $g$ to convert this into a $(0,2)$ tensor by defining $\widetilde{P}_T:V\times V\to\Bbb{R}$ as
\begin{align}
\widetilde{P}_T(v,w)&:=g(P_T(v),w)=\sum_{i=1}^k\tau_ig(v,t_i)g(w,t_i),
\end{align}
i.e
\begin{align}
\widetilde{P}_T=\sum_{i=1}^k\tau_ig(\cdot,t_i)\otimes g(\cdot, t_i).
\end{align}
In terms of indices, this says $(P_T)_{\mu\nu}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\tau_i\cdot (t_i)_{\mu}(t_i)_{\nu}$, and so $(P_S)_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\tau_i\cdot (t_i)_{\mu}(t_i)_{\nu}$.

In SR and GR, the case of interest is when $\dim V=4$, $g$ has Lorentzian signature, $\dim T=1$ and hence $\dim S=3$. In this case, we only have to deal with a since normalized vector $t_1=u$ as you denote it. Hence, the ($(0,2)$ version of the) projection onto the subspace spanned by $u$ is
\begin{align}
(P_T)_{\mu\nu}&=g(u,u)\cdot u_{\mu}u_{\nu}.
\end{align}
Hence, the ($(0,2)$ version of the) projection onto $S$, which you have simply denoted $P$ is now simplified to
\begin{align}
P_{\mu\nu}\equiv (P_S)_{\mu\nu}=g_{\mu\nu}-g(u,u)u_{\mu}u_{\nu}.
\end{align}
If $g(u,u)=+1$, then you get exactly the result you claimed. If $g(u,u)=-1$, then there’s an extra sign. So, observe that the spacelikeness/timelikeness of the vector and your choice of metric signature convention matter at the end.
And of course, linking back to physics, in practice we often take this vector $u$ to be the normalized instantaneous velocity of an observer. The decomposition $V=S\oplus T$ then corresponds to this observer’s instantaneous notion of ‘space vs time’ decomposition.

I want to stress that the fundamental concept here, namely the decompositions $(*)$ and $(**)$, is very trivial. In fact in Euclidean geometry (i.e when $g$ is an actual positive-definite inner product), we would have all $\tau_i=+1$, and then the decomposition $(*)$ becomes one of the first thing you learn in middle/high school when it comes to vectors, and ‘dropping perpendiculars’ by projecting onto each of the orthonormal vectors and adding up the contributions. The only extra difficulty in the case of general signature is the need to be careful with signs.

Take an arbitrary vector $X^a$. Its projection along $u^a$ direction will be $X^bu_b u^a$. Then the component orthogonal to $u^a$ will be simply $X^a-X^bu_bu^a = (\delta^a_b - u_bu^a)X^b={P^a}_bX^b$

You can approach this from elementary linear algebra. For the first part we will deal with Euclidean vectors so there will be no distinguished upper and lower indices.
With a unit vector $\vec e$ the projector along it is $(\vec e \circ \vec e) \vec a = \vec e (\vec e \cdot \vec a)$. In components $(\vec e \circ \vec e)_{ij} = e_ie_j$.
The projector that projects to the part orthogonal to this is obviously $\mathbf{1} - \vec e \circ \vec e$. In components this is $\delta_{ij} - e_i e_j$.
In general relativity, we now have the issue that covariant and contravariant 4-vectors and their components must be distinguished (btw, the same is already true in non-orthonormal coordinate systems on euclidean space). So we now have upper and lower indices.
The $P_{\mu\nu}$ you give projects a contravariant vector to a covariant vector. In this setting the unit matrix of above must be replaced by the metric $g_{\mu\nu}$ (as this maps a contravariant vector to the corresponding covariant one). With this simple adaption you get your formula from the elementary one.
Finally, it is quite straight-forward to verify that this is the correct projector:

Take any vector $x^\mu$, then $P_{\mu\nu}x^\mu$ is what you get when applying the projector $P$ to it, then we get:
$$ P_{\mu\nu} x^\nu u^\mu = g_{\mu\nu} x^\nu u^\mu - u_\mu u_\nu x^\nu u^\mu =  u^\nu x^\nu - \underbrace{u^\mu u_\mu}_{=1} u^\nu x_\nu = 0. $$
So the result is of the projection is orthogonal to $u^\mu$.

It remains to be shown that $P$ is actually a projector, namely idempotent, (that is $P^2 = P$):
$$ P_{\mu\nu}g^{\nu\lambda}P_{\lambda \kappa} = g_{\mu\nu} \underbrace{g^{\nu\lambda} g_{\lambda\kappa}}_{=\delta^\nu_\kappa} - \underbrace{g_{\mu\nu} g^{\nu\lambda} u_\lambda}_{=u_\mu} u_\kappa - u_\mu \underbrace{u_\nu g^{\nu\lambda} g_{\lambda\kappa}}_{=u_\kappa} + u_\mu \underbrace{u_\nu g^{\nu \lambda} u_\lambda}_{=1} u_\kappa = g_{\mu\kappa} - u_\mu u_\kappa = P_{\mu\kappa}.$$


